# How is the 'e--' expression used in this simple exponent example?

Tags: c#, exponent

I understand every cog in this code with the exception of one part: the "e--;" within the While loop. Can anybody explain its importance to me?

```
public class Power 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
        int e;
        int result;

        for(int i=0; i < 10; i++) 
        {
            result = 1;
            e = i;

            while(e > 0) 
            {
                result *= 2;
                e--;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("2 to the {0} power is {1}", i, result));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is a homework assignment, I guess that could explain this.  Otherwise, use [Math.Pow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and call it a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here is to simply multiply `result` by 2 `i` times.  It does this by setting `e` to `i`, subtracting one each iteration of the loop, and looping while it's positive.  This means that the `while` loop will always loop `i` times.  You could just as easily (and arguably more clearly) write:

```
for(int e = 0; e < i; e++)
    result *= 2;
```

Comment: So if i is equal to 1, e is then set to i and the "result *= 2;" is computed. From there, e is then decremented back to 0, right? I believe my fundamental error in comprehension is that e = i and NOT i = e. That way, the output would be that i is still increasing by 1 until 9 and output everytime, whereas e is decremented every time to allow for the while loop to always occur so long as e > 0. Does that sound correct? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user3002707 `i` is never mutated inside of the loop.  `e` is redefined in each iteration of the loop.  It is creating a *nested* loop such that, for each iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop iterates `i` times.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking at a [postfix decrement operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691363%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

It evaluates the value of `e` and then subtracts one from the value; since it's a standalone statement, it simply subtracts one from `e`'s value.

Comment: The question implies (and [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21993922/c-sharp-simple-exponent-example/21993992#comment33332552_21993985) explicitly states) that it's not asking what the definition of the operator is, but rather *why* it's used here.  What is the *point* in decrimenting `e` by one in this program?

Comment: Thanks you, @Servy. Sorry for my ambiguity. So exactly Why is it there?

Comment: @user3002707 I explain that in my answer.

Comment: @Servy that wasn't my read on the vaguely-worded question, but it is a good question.  As far as I can see, `e` has no point in existing, given that its value is evaluated in neither the for loop nor the output.

Comment: @48klocs The linked comment clarifies the ambiguity, making it clear that the OP *does* understand what the decriment operator does.  As for `e` being pointless.  It's not pointless.  It most certainly has a point, and it is used.  It's used in the line `while(e > 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

The `e--` just decrements the value of `e`. It is equivalent to `e = e - 1;`.

The reason you decrement the value is to eventually exit of the `while` loop; once you set `e` to the value of `i`, the loop will run indefinitely unless the value of `e` becomes less or equal to zero, which makes the `while` loop condition of `e > 0` false.

In the larger picture, you are using `e` to stored the current value of `i` and then use it to execute `i` times the statement `result *= 2;`. In other words, you are using `e` to count how many times the variable `result` needs to be multiplied by `2` during the current iteration of the outer `for` loop.

This is similar to doing something like,

```
for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) 
{
    result = 1;
    e = 0;

    for (e = i; e > 0; e--) 
    {
        result *= 2;
    }
}
```

Since the `while` loop is really acting as a `for` loop.

Comment: Can you give me more detail? I understand that it decrements it, however, I do not see the significance of doing so.

Answer (score 1):

```
while(e > 0)
```

This means that your loop will run as long as `e` is greater than zero. `e--` is decrementing `e's value` on each iteration. If you didn't decrement it inside of your loop then you will get an infinite loop because your condition will become always **true** and your loop won't end.

Answer (score 1):

`e` is your counter variable. It will repeat the `while` loop until the result has been multiplied the specified number of times (which is whatever `i` is when the loop started). As others have stated, `e--` just decrements the value of `e` by one. You can read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc3z3k8c.aspx). This means that, in the code you provided, it will multiply `result` by 2 `e` times which mathematically will compute `2^i` (i.e. `2^0 = 1`, `2^1 = 2`, `2^2 = 4`, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

e-- means it will decrease 1 in each loop, e++ will increase 1

check this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36x43w8w.aspx